# Java runOnUiThread and Thread.sleep

Tags: java, android, sip, java-threads

I have this method from a separate class wherein when the call ends, the color of my ImageView changes from red to white. Sample code below:

```
public void endOfCall(){

    ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            TargetDetails.oncall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TargetDetails.endcall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    try{
        call.endCall();
    }catch (SipException se) {}

    call.close();

    //this is just a representation; not the actual code
    if(true){
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    //new intent here
}
```

The problem starts when it goes to the 'if' condition where I put the Thread.sleep. It waits 10seconds before the code below gets executed

```
TargetDetails.oncall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TargetDetails.endcall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I think I am missing something here regarding the Thread.sleep. I just wanna get rid of it but I'm not sure of any alternative aside from that. Help. Thanks.

Comment: if you call `endOfCall` from the uiThread, it´ll sleep for 10 seconds, then finish the block and run the pending tasks such as the visibility changes...

Comment: Why is the thread sleeping here ?

Comment: It's part of the process..it sleeps for a few secs(not really 10secs)  then proceeds to another intent where it makes a call again. That's why I put the sleep after the visibility coz I thought that it would process the visibility first then the sleep.

Comment: You mention that the method runs in a separate class, but does it also run in a separate thread? You should only use runOnUiThread if you are in a runnable in another thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead of putting thread to sleep.

So instead of your `if(true) {.....}` try this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        //new intent here
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: ok. will try this. will get back to you after a few mins. thanks.

Comment: it now works. but is there a way to know the counter? like if it's already 1 or 2, etc?

Comment: You can extend `Runnable` so it accepts int as a constructor value and use your custom Runnable instead

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't really catch what you are talking about. I'm newbie in android programming so I'm still lost. :(