# Function to change background color crashing app

Tags: java, android

This funcion is crashing my app and im not sure why.

```
    public void whileLoopForChange(){
    while (gameRunning = true){
        View someView = findViewById(R.id.screen);
        final View root = someView.getRootView();
        Random rand = new Random();
        final int value = rand.nextInt(15);
        if(lvl<10){
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(value == 1){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Red));
                        currentColor = "red";
                    }else if(value == 2){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Pink));
                        currentColor = "pink";
                    }else if(value == 3){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Orange));
                        currentColor = "orange";
                    }else if(value == 4){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Blue));
                        currentColor = "blue";
                    }else if(value == 5){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Green));
                        currentColor = "green";
                    }else if(value == 6){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.White));
                        currentColor = "white";
                    }else if(value == 7){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Black));
                        currentColor = "black";
                    }else if(value == 8){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Salmon));
                        currentColor = "salmon";
                    }else if(value == 9){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Violet));
                        currentColor = "violet";
                    }else if(value == 10){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Cyan));
                        currentColor = "cyan";
                    }else if(value == 11){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.DarkGray));
                        currentColor = "darkgray";
                    }else if(value == 12){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Gray));
                        currentColor = "gray";
                    }else if(value == 13){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Chocolate));
                        currentColor = "chocolate";
                    }else if(value == 14){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Silver));
                        currentColor = "silver";
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }else if(lvl<15 && lvl>9) {
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(value == 1){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Red));
                        currentColor = "red";
                    }else if(value == 2){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Pink));
                        currentColor = "pink";
                    }else if(value == 3){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Orange));
                        currentColor = "orange";
                    }else if(value == 4){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Blue));
                        currentColor = "blue";
                    }else if(value == 5){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Green));
                        currentColor = "green";
                    }else if(value == 6){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.White));
                        currentColor = "white";
                    }else if(value == 7){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Black));
                        currentColor = "black";
                    }else if(value == 8){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Salmon));
                        currentColor = "salmon";
                    }else if(value == 9){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Violet));
                        currentColor = "violet";
                    }else if(value == 10){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Cyan));
                        currentColor = "cyan";
                    }else if(value == 11){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.DarkGray));
                        currentColor = "darkgray";
                    }else if(value == 12){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Gray));
                        currentColor = "gray";
                    }else if(value == 13){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Chocolate));
                        currentColor = "chocolate";
                    }else if(value == 14){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Silver));
                        currentColor = "silver";
                    }
                }
            }, 750);
        }else if(lvl<20 && lvl>14){
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(value == 1){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Red));
                        currentColor = "red";
                    }else if(value == 2){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Pink));
                        currentColor = "pink";
                    }else if(value == 3){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Orange));
                        currentColor = "orange";
                    }else if(value == 4){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Blue));
                        currentColor = "blue";
                    }else if(value == 5){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Green));
                        currentColor = "green";
                    }else if(value == 6){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.White));
                        currentColor = "white";
                    }else if(value == 7){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Black));
                        currentColor = "black";
                    }else if(value == 8){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Salmon));
                        currentColor = "salmon";
                    }else if(value == 9){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Violet));
                        currentColor = "violet";
                    }else if(value == 10){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Cyan));
                        currentColor = "cyan";
                    }else if(value == 11){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.DarkGray));
                        currentColor = "darkgray";
                    }else if(value == 12){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Gray));
                        currentColor = "gray";
                    }else if(value == 13){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Chocolate));
                        currentColor = "chocolate";
                    }else if(value == 14){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Silver));
                        currentColor = "silver";
                    }
                }
            }, 600);
        }else if(lvl<30 && lvl>19){
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(value == 1){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Red));
                        currentColor = "red";
                    }else if(value == 2){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Pink));
                        currentColor = "pink";
                    }else if(value == 3){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Orange));
                        currentColor = "orange";
                    }else if(value == 4){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Blue));
                        currentColor = "blue";
                    }else if(value == 5){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Green));
                        currentColor = "green";
                    }else if(value == 6){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.White));
                        currentColor = "white";
                    }else if(value == 7){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Black));
                        currentColor = "black";
                    }else if(value == 8){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Salmon));
                        currentColor = "salmon";
                    }else if(value == 9){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Violet));
                        currentColor = "violet";
                    }else if(value == 10){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Cyan));
                        currentColor = "cyan";
                    }else if(value == 11){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.DarkGray));
                        currentColor = "darkgray";
                    }else if(value == 12){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Gray));
                        currentColor = "gray";
                    }else if(value == 13){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Chocolate));
                        currentColor = "chocolate";
                    }else if(value == 14){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Silver));
                        currentColor = "silver";
                    }
                }
            }, 550);
        }else if(lvl<50 && lvl>29){
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(value == 1){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Red));
                        currentColor = "red";
                    }else if(value == 2){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Pink));
                        currentColor = "pink";
                    }else if(value == 3){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Orange));
                        currentColor = "orange";
                    }else if(value == 4){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Blue));
                        currentColor = "blue";
                    }else if(value == 5){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Green));
                        currentColor = "green";
                    }else if(value == 6){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.White));
                        currentColor = "white";
                    }else if(value == 7){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Black));
                        currentColor = "black";
                    }else if(value == 8){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Salmon));
                        currentColor = "salmon";
                    }else if(value == 9){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Violet));
                        currentColor = "violet";
                    }else if(value == 10){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Cyan));
                        currentColor = "cyan";
                    }else if(value == 11){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.DarkGray));
                        currentColor = "darkgray";
                    }else if(value == 12){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Gray));
                        currentColor = "gray";
                    }else if(value == 13){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Chocolate));
                        currentColor = "chocolate";
                    }else if(value == 14){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Silver));
                        currentColor = "silver";
                    }
                }
            }, 500);
        }else if(lvl<49){
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(value == 1){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Red));
                        currentColor = "red";
                    }else if(value == 2){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Pink));
                        currentColor = "pink";
                    }else if(value == 3){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Orange));
                        currentColor = "orange";
                    }else if(value == 4){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Blue));
                        currentColor = "blue";
                    }else if(value == 5){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Green));
                        currentColor = "green";
                    }else if(value == 6){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.White));
                        currentColor = "white";
                    }else if(value == 7){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Black));
                        currentColor = "black";
                    }else if(value == 8){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Salmon));
                        currentColor = "salmon";
                    }else if(value == 9){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Violet));
                        currentColor = "violet";
                    }else if(value == 10){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Cyan));
                        currentColor = "cyan";
                    }else if(value == 11){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.DarkGray));
                        currentColor = "darkgray";
                    }else if(value == 12){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Gray));
                        currentColor = "gray";
                    }else if(value == 13){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Chocolate));
                        currentColor = "chocolate";
                    }else if(value == 14){
                        root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Silver));
                        currentColor = "silver";
                    }
                }
            }, 350);
        }
    }
```

The app runs fine when I remove the function and the call to it.
Im pretty new to android but have java experiance.
The call for this function is in the onCreate method after everything that defaultly comes in that method.
I havent put anything in the layout xml file and i have no other functions but onCreate in my main activity.

EDIT 1: Removing the timer makes the app not crash. How would I replace the timer function with something that makes the code run after for say a second?

EDIT 2: 
Logcat:                                                    --------- beginning of crash
07-28 15:15:37.259 32203-32203/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: io.eliot.colorstop, PID: 32203
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.eliot.colorstop/io.eliot.colorstop.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference
                                                       at io.eliot.colorstop.MainActivity.whileLoopForChange(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                       at io.eliot.colorstop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

After reading the logcat it seems that its getting the root view that crashes it.

Comment: what is the logcat? put here to better help

Comment: can you show us the error?

Comment: ` while (gameRunning = true){` sets it to true, does not compare

Comment: You are accessing the view object in a different thread, run in the main thread.

Comment: Can you expand on running in a differnt thread pls?

Comment: Posted logcat under edit 2

Answer (score 2):

Timer runs code in new Thread. Use runOnUiThread function

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Your code here.
                    }
                });
```

Comment: But then how would I make it run every second? Thread.sleep(1000); isnt working

Comment: Try to use Handlers 

[sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654421/java-runonuithread-and-thread-sleep) 


[sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)